# Perfect scores for multiclass classification

Tags: cross-validation, multiclass-classification, overfitting, f1score

I am working on a multiclass classification problem with 3 (1, 2, 3) classes being perfectly distributed. (70 instances of each class resulting in (210, 8) dataframe). Now my data has all the 3 classes distributed in order i.e first 70 instances are class1, next 70 instances are class 2 and last 70 instances are class 3. I know that this kind of distribution will lead to good score on train set but poor score on test set as the test set has classes that the model has not seen. So I used `stratify` parameter in `train_test_split`. My code:-

```
# SPLITTING 
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data2, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 
69, stratify = y)

cross_val_model = cross_val_score(pipe, train_x, train_y, cv = 5,
                              n_jobs = -1, scoring = 'f1_macro')
s_score = cross_val_model.mean()


def objective(trial):

    model__n_neighbors = trial.suggest_int('model__n_neighbors', 1, 20)
    model__metric = trial.suggest_categorical('model__metric', ['euclidean', 'manhattan', 
    'minkowski'])
    model__weights = trial.suggest_categorical('model__weights', ['uniform', 'distance'])

    params = {'model__n_neighbors' : model__n_neighbors, 
          'model__metric' : model__metric, 
          'model__weights' : model__weights}

    pipe.set_params(**params)

    return np.mean( cross_val_score(pipe, train_x, train_y, cv = 5, 
                                    n_jobs = -1, scoring = 'f1_macro'))

knn_study = optuna.create_study(direction = 'maximize')
knn_study.optimize(objective, n_trials = 10)

knn_study.best_params
optuna_gave_score = knn_study.best_value    

pipe.set_params(**knn_study.best_params)
pipe.fit(train_x, train_y)
pred = pipe.predict(test_x)
c_matrix = confusion_matrix(test_y, pred)
c_report = classification_report(test_y, pred)
```

Now the problem is that I am getting perfect scores on everything. The f1 macro score from performing cv is 0.898. Below are my confusion matrix and classification report:-

```
14  0   0 
0   14  0 
0   0   14
```

Classification Report:-

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

       1       1.00      1.00      1.00        14
       2       1.00      1.00      1.00        14
       3       1.00      1.00      1.00        14

accuracy                            1.00        42
macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00        42
weighted avg    1.00      1.00      1.00        42
```

Am I overfitting or what?

Comment: Everything looks fine to me (just wondering what `knn_study.best_params` does, but I guess it is just printing the best parameters), overfitting is when your accuracy increases on train set, but decreases on test set. Here your accuracy is 1.0 on test set, so everything is perfect. It means that your classes are 'clustered' enough so the algorithm is able to give 42 correct predictions out of 42 test values. It is anyway not really possible to overfit on a KNN algorithm, it is an issue that mostly affects Neural Networks, which KNN is not.

Comment: @Ubikuity yes `knn_study.best_params` gives the best parameters. Are you sure that it is not overfitting? Because one rarely gets 90% score in real world models. Here I am getting 100% which makes me believe something is wrong!

Comment: Also the fact that I have used `stratify = y` on an extremely balanced dataset. Maybe that might be the reason? I dunno what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: i just checked the split function (from sklearn) and still cannot figure what stratify does, would you explain it to me ?

Comment: @Ubikuity This stratify parameter makes a split so that the proportion of values in the sample produced will be the same as the proportion of values provided to parameter stratify.

For example, if variable y is a binary categorical variable with values 0 and 1 and there are 25% of zeros and 75% of ones, stratify=y will make sure that your random split has 25% of 0's and 75% of 1's.

Comment: @Ubikuity basically it will make sure that both train and test set contain equal proportion of both the classes.

Comment: Ok, it explains why you have 14 of each class in your dataset. Really nothing seems off with your model, just enjoy the 100% accuracy (remember that 42 samples is not much samples). If you want to investigate why your model works so well, try plotting different features (seems you have 8 here) with colors for each classes and see if it is clustered (I can explain with some code if this is a bit unclear).

Comment: Yes please, if you can! That'd be great

Comment: Alright, i'm writing it and trying to explain how to understand the plots, should be out in 5-10min.

Comment: Taking a bit longer but definitly coming out ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay.

Having 100% accuracy means that the task is easy enough and the network has no trouble performing it.

Just a quick reminder about how [K-NN algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) works : During training, you put your data in it and it somehow remembers the data. Then when using it on new values (testing here), it just looks for the nearest neighbours and look at the classes of these ones. After finding that K Nearest Neighbours are from class X, it tells that the input was from class X.

[image: KNN]

Here for example, the algorithm finds out that most points (the 'most' depends on the K you choose) around your input are from class 2, so the input should belong to class 2 as well.

Now here is how i would try to analyse the data you send in the KNN :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data2 = np.random.randn(40, 2)  # Replace with your data
y = np.random.randint(0, 3, 40)  # Replace with your data
data2[:, 1] = data2[:, 1] + 4*y  # Replace with your data


for feature in range(data2.shape[1]):
    plt.figure()
    for sample in range(data2.shape[0]):
        plt.title('feature ' + str(feature))
        plt.scatter(data2[np.where(y == 0), feature].squeeze(), y[np.where(y == 0)], color='red')
        plt.scatter(data2[np.where(y == 1), feature].squeeze(), y[np.where(y == 1)], color='blue')
        plt.scatter(data2[np.where(y == 2), feature].squeeze(), y[np.where(y == 2)], color='green')
    plt.show()
```

In my example, I have 40 samples with 2 features each and 3 classes and here are the 2 different plots I get :

[image: Plot1]
[image: Plot2]

On these plots, you get each class values on a different line. So you can see if your classes are clustered or not. A feature which output something similar to feature 0 is nearly useless for the KNN classification as classes seem to have random values and are not forming clusters. A feature like feature 1 is a feature that provide much information to the classifier as we can clearly see the difference between classes.

Hope this helps, if you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Was facing some health issues. Regarding your answer, should I perform this after fitting my final model? Also what about learning curves to detect over/under fitting?

Comment: @spectre You can perform the analysis whenever you want, we usually do it before applying KNN algorithm because this type of data analysis is an indicator that shows if KNN will actually work well or not. About the overfitting and learning curves, I though it would be clearer now, but these concepts do not apply to KNN algorithm, curves and overfitting is an issue that **neural networks** have to cope with. KNN is a much simpler algorithm and it does not really face the overfitting problem.

Comment: I'll try to explain briefly why KNN isn't affected by overfitting with an example. Let's have a NN (Neural Network) that tries to approximate the line x = 2y in 2D, we feed x in the network and it returns y. your samples may not be perfect, for example they may be (1, 2.3), (5, 9.5), (3, 5.4), ... So when you start your training, during each epoch it will go over your set of sample, predict and change the parameters of the network to give more accurate prediction.

Comment: The beginning of the training is when the NN learns the 'general relations', so it does the big part of the job, but not the perfect fit. So here it may find something like x = 1.9y. Overfitting is when after going over and over your set of samples multiples times, your network is super accurate on your training set (because he found some super complicated polynomial relation that perfetly describes the training set), but it is not able anymore to generalize the relation to other cases. So that is why we avoid this by checking the learning curves over the epochs.

Comment: Now KNN isn't really affected by this issue because KNN just stores the data values when you send them to it, there are no epochs, you just train once on your dataset. Sending more data only creates more points on the graph I draw on my post. So it may create more points that are out of main area of a class, but since we anyway look for K neighbours each time, it isn't really an issue (the more data we fit in, the bigger K gets).

Comment: Hope I made it clearer (not sure about that tho). It isn't necessary to understand everything I wrote, just remember that KNN (K-Nearest Neighbour) is not a NN (Neural Network) and thus is not affected by overfitting, you should not worry about it when using a KNN.

Comment: Ok but I have read in many articles that for k=1 in knn, we get perfect scores because we are overfitting. When k=1 the nearest neighbor to the point is that point itself. Hence we would always get 100% scores on all test set. I am saying this because I get k=1 in some of my hyperparameter tuning runs. Also sometimes k=15 and still I get 100% scores so that is the reason I am getting confused

Comment: @spectre Be careful,having k=1 means that the nearest neighbour will determine the class of your input, but your testing base is not sent to the model during 'training', so when testing, it will just find the nearest neighbour *from the training set* to determine the class (so it won't turn into 100% acc). But I agree on the fact that using k=1 is greedy and can create what you understand as overfitting, maybe try forcing a higher k by changing this line of code `model__n_neighbors = trial.suggest_int('model__n_neighbors', 1, 20)`.

Comment: Overall, I really feel like you underestimate the ability of your network to give the correct prediction, your task may not be so hard and since your dataset is not very massive, it is not such a big deal that your network gets 42 correct predictions in a row. A quick but not rigorous rule is to add 1 correct and 1 false prediction to your accuracy if your dataset is too small. So here it would turn your accuracy to 43/44 = 98% accuracy.

Comment: Ok understood now. Thank you for the elaborate explanation! I have marked your answer as the best. Also can you take a look @ another question that I have? Here is the link    https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/99930/learning-curves